# How to add my site to Google Chrome's whitelist autoplay with sound?

Tags: google-chrome, autoplay

I know Google's autoplay policy does not allow sound to be played during autoplay, but some sites can still autoplay with sound, such as YouTube, Twitch, Netflix,... And I know there is a whitelist with more than 1000 sites that allow autoplay with sounds. How can I get my website on the whitelist?

I have read Chrome autoplay policy via here [https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay]
And I found the blog that they talk about improve autoplay [https://blog.google/products/chrome/improving-autoplay-chrome]
Are there any way I can do to add my site in white list?